# Unhandled 'error' event with fs in node js

Tags: node.js, events, exception, fs

I tried to replace images data with File System but i could n't find what is the mistake.how can i resolve that

Here is the code

```html
fs.readFile(background, function (err, data) {

        fs.writeFile(backgroundImage, backgroundimageBuffer.data, function (err) {

            im.resize({
                srcPath:backgroundImage,
                dstPath: background,
                width: backgroundDimensions.width,
                height: backgroundDimensions.height
            }, function(err, stdout, stderr){
                 if(err) throw err;
                console.log('resized image to fit within ' + backgroundDimensions.width + ' and ' + backgroundDimensions.height);
            });

            console.log("success");
        });
    });
```

Error

```html
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn convert ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:874:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
```

Comment: Does file background exists?

Comment: yes it exists already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure that the file in variable `background` exists and also file in the variable `backgroundImage` is written to filesystem successfully before it is processed by `im` .

It appears that im is spawning a child process and that is unable to find the source file.

Also, I suggest to Use the code below to log the specific file handling error

```
fs.readFile(background, function (err, data) {
    if(err){
      //this will log specific error to file
      return console.dir(err);
    }
    console.log('background file read');
    fs.writeFile(backgroundImage, backgroundimageBuffer.data, function (err) {
    if(err){
      //this will log specific error to file
      return console.dir(err);
    }
        console.log('backgroundImage file written');
        im.resize({
            srcPath:backgroundImage,
            dstPath: background,
            width: backgroundDimensions.width,
            height: backgroundDimensions.height
        }, function(err, stdout, stderr){
             if(err) {console.log('resized error');console.dir(err); throw err;}
            console.log('resized image to fit within ' + backgroundDimensions.width + ' and ' + backgroundDimensions.height);
        });

        console.log("success");
    });
});
```

Comment: it exists ,i double checked on that

Comment: background file read
backgroundImage file written
success
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Comment: I think library file issue wait i will let you know

Comment: yeah, looks like library file is trying to reference a non-existent file or probably you haven't supplied the required arguments